# SwiftDate - string to date

Tags: ios, swift, swiftdate

I use the [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) library but I can't transform my string to date. This code return null

```
 let date = "Tue, 19 Sep 2017 15:43:57 GMT".date(format: .custom("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"))
```

Would anyone know why?

Comment: What locale are you in? Is your device/simulator setup to use English?

Comment: No, my device is in french. But i use a custom format so I think it doesn't matter

Comment: The order of date components is custom but `Tue`(sday) is doubtless English. I guess `Mar` will be recognized on a French system.

Comment: It's just ... I change the language in English and it works. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Louis don't you want to make it work for users regardless of the language in their device settings?

Comment: Yes, i will set region to en. I change the device language just to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works now :

```
let region = Region(tz: TimeZoneName.gmt, cal: CalendarName.gregorian, loc: LocaleName.englishUnitedStates)
let date = "Tue, 19 Sep 2017 15:43:57 GMT".date(format: .custom("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"), fromRegion: region)
```

Thank you for your help!