# Swift string convert to SwiftDate

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdateformatter, swiftdate

How can I convert `12 Oct 2018 at 10:45:46 AM` to [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) `DateInRegion`?
My code returns nil:

```
    let ds = "12 Oct 2018 at 10:45:46 AM"
    let region = Region(tz: TimeZone.current,
                        cal: CalendarName.gregorian.calendar,
                        loc: Locale.init(identifier: "en"))
    let format = DateFormat.custom("EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz")
    var str = ds.date(format: format, fromRegion: region)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwiftDate - string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305634/swiftdate-string-to-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your dateformat `,` is not available, the correct format is

```
let ds = "12 Oct 2018 at 10:45:46 AM"
let format = DateFormat.custom("dd MMM yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss a")
```

for additional info you get [old answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469172/show-am-pm-in-capitals-in-swift) from SO.for dateformats you get detailed answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524651/convert-nsdate-to-string-in-ios-swift/42524767#42524767)

Comment: i just changed the EEE to MM and it works now. thanks!